# How do you calculate the depth of penetration in a Schlumberger array?

Tags: geophysics, measurements, in-situ-measurements, electromagnetism

In a resistivity survey, how do we calculate the depth of penetration for a Schlumberger array?

Comment: I thought I had this in a book (GSL Field Geophysics pocket book), but alas not. Of course the electrical field is continuous so you are going to have a depth that represents something like "half the sensitivity is shallower than this".

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: 0.2 times the total length of your cable(s).

100m rollout --> ~20m depth

Bear in mind that the deeper you get, the more you have to be careful with your data interpretation. Also if you do a roll-along your depth doesn't get deeper.

Long answer see [Bernard J (2003): Short note on the depth of investigation of electrical methods. Heritage Geophysics](http://www.heritagegeophysics.com/papers/Depth_of_investigation.pdf).